# firebase retrieve data by using orderByKey() and equalTo()

Tags: firebase

So I'm trying to find the data "aaaaabbbbbbaaaa" in this structure:

```
disney
 studentList
 -Jh46tlaNFx_YmgA8iMJ: "aaaaabbbbbbaaaa"
 -Jh474kAvoekE4hC7W3b:"54ce1cbec4335cd3186105dc"
```

I used this

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://disney.firebaseio.com/");
ref.child("studentList").orderByKey().equalTo("54ca2c11d1afc1612871624a").on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```

But I got nothing back. What was wrong?
What should I use?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In the data sample that you've given, there is no node under `studenList` with a **key** of `54ca2c11d1afc1612871624a`.

Your keys are `-Jh46tlaNFx_YmgA8iMJ` and `-Jh474kAvoekE4hC7W3b`. You can easily determine this yourself by:

```
ref.child("studentList").orderByKey().on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.key()); // on newer SDKs, this may be snapshot.key
});
```

You seem to want to order the nodes by their value, but that is not an operation that is available on Firebase at the moment. Firebase can only [query children by a value of a named property](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/orderbychild.html), the [key](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/orderbykey.html) or its [priority](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/orderbypriority.html). So if you'd change the data structure to:

```
disney
 studentList
   -Jh46tlaNFx_YmgA8iMJ:
     name: "aaaaabbbbbbaaaa"
   -Jh474kAvoekE4hC7W3b:
     name: "54ce1cbec4335cd3186105dc"
```

You could get the children order by name with:

```
ref.child("studentList")
   .orderByChild("name")
   .equalTo("54ca2c11d1afc1612871624a")
   .on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
      console.log(snapshot.val());
    });
```

Just a side node: if your actual node values are like the ones in the sample you provided, you might want to consider using the values as the keys; they already seem pretty unique to my untrained eye.

Comment: Firebase can only query children **by a value of a named property**, did you mean that the key() doesn't count as a name?

Comment: The key is not a named property, but you can also order by key (as you did with `orderByKey()`. What you can't do is order by the **unnamed** value of a node, as seems to be what you want. If you really want that data structure, you could stuff the value into `.priority` (see `setPriority` in the docs) and use `orderByPriority`. But it is much more common nowadays (since Firebase added `orderByChild`) to name the property or (if it doesn't really have a name) use it as the key itself.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it was added after your question was made, the solution here https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data?hl=en#ordering-by-value tackles your need right away:

```
ref("studentList").orderByValue().on("value", function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(data) {
    console.log(data.val());
  });
});
```