# How to update Firebase data for Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

There is firebase data,the key is not FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid

```
["location": {"-Khpr_PAuGSVngNspTVW" =
                  {
                     "lat" = "24.370078858713";
                     "long" = "14.11361694336";
                  };
              "-KhH-LaOcWgwaGYbPGIX" =
                  {
                     "lat" = "22.379264";
                     "long" = "13.3213213";
                  };
]
```

How can I update one of the lat or long, I try updated but it just extra create a table inside location .

```
 let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
 databaseRef.child("location").updateChildValues(["lat": 11.324231])
```

That is work!but I don't want to write user key myself

```
 let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
 databaseRef.child("location").child("ben").updateChildValues(["lat": 11.324231])
```

Comment: i do  not understant  your question . could you add more context

Comment: @Nazmul Hasan `let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
        databaseRef.child("location").child("-Khpr_PAuGSVngNspTVW").updateChildValues(["lat": 11.324231])` It can update. but if I click button to update this data .how can update one of lat or long if I will not put user key <-Khpr_PAuGSVngNspTVW

Comment: what is the problem with `FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid` ?

Comment: @Nazmul Hasan like this: Khpr_PAuGSVngNspTVW. may be user key. what method can get each user key?

Comment: do you interested with  `.orderByKey().limitToLast(1)`

Comment: @Nazmul Hasan let userRef = ref.("location").orderByKey().limitToLast(1)                                       userRef.updateChildValues(["lat": 11.324231])   is like that??

Comment: yea ..try this way may be can helped you

Comment: @Nazmul Hasan ` let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
                databaseRef.child("location").orderByKey().limitToLast(1)
                databaseRef.updateChildValues(["lat": 11.324231])`   it show error message: Value of type 'FIRDatabaseReference' has no member 'orderByKey' how to solve this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28262803/firebase-retrieve-data-by-using-orderbykey-and-equalto#

Answer (score 2):

If you know which user it is, just include that in the reference path.

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
let userRef = ref.("location").child("-Khpr_PAuGSVngNspTVW")
userRef.updateChildValues(["lat": 11.324231])
```

Comment: yeah.I know. which method can don't need entry user key myself? I try use queryOrderedByKey() it aslo extra create a table inside location .

Comment: @Kelvin How do you know which node to update if you don't know which user it's for?